# How to show that for an element $x$ in DGA cohomology it is true that $[x]=[-x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, differential-graded-algebras

Perhaps it is a really dumb question, but I want to use this property and it seems that it must hold. However, if one takes a specific homogeneous element $x$ of a differential graded algebra, then proving this statement is showing that $2x=d(something)$ and I don't see an easy way to find $something$.

Thank you.

---

(Edit)
Commentators convinced me that the statement is not generally true.

Comment: It's certainly not true in general.  Maybe the situation you are interested in has some special properties that would make it true.

Comment: @EricWofsey Hm, actually, cohomologies of my DGA are isomorhic to cohomologies of a certain topological space? Might it make the statement true?

Comment: Plenty of topological spaces have cohomology rings where this is NOT true.  For example, if $R$ is a commutative ring which does NOT have characteristic 2, then for any space $X$, $H_0(X;R)$ doesn't have this property.